# Display json data in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, post

I have a post that runs on page load. I am trying to get data objects in json to use on my page and in my controller so I am trying to store the value in Angular scope.

I do not know where I have gone wrong but I cant get the value and when I console.log I get

> angular.js:11655 ReferenceError: data is not defined

I want to store

```
c_name

max_slots

base_image
```

**Summery of what I need**

I need my array objects listed above stored in scope variables so that I may use them in my html and else where in my JavaScript controller.

**My json**

```
   {data: Array(1), status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}
config
:
{method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), url: "http://www.site.co.uk/one/two/getdata", date: {…}, …}
data
:
Array(1)
0
:
c_name
:
"ben"
d_text
:
[]
max_slots
:
2
resolution
:
(2) [1920, 1080]
slots
:
Array(3)
0
:
{path_image: "", base_image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…O7/aaFdrXd6na2UApSIJEwod/rWVlSUUk2h2Gbknfi6P/2Q==", slot_id: 1}
1
:
{path_image: "", base_image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…O7/aaFdrXd6na2UApSIJEwod/rWVlSUUk2h2Gbknfi6P/2Q==", slot_id: 2}
2
:
{path_image: "", base_image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…O7/aaFdrXd6na2UApSIJEwod/rWVlSUUk2h2Gbknfi6P/2Q==", slot_id: 3}
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__v
:
0
_id
:
"59c92d6f45b79c8c110ee6ab"
__proto__
:
Object
```

My script I am trying to get the data

**My JavaScript**

```
    $scope.GetData = function () {
        $http({
            url: "http://www.site.co.uk/one/two/getdata",
            method: "POST",
            date: {},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(function (response) {
            // success
            console.log('you have received the data ');
            console.log(response);
            // $scope.base_image = response.base_image; $scope.c_name = response.c_name;
            $scope.c_name = data.c_name;
            $scope.max_slots = data.max_slots;
            $scope.slot_image = data.slots.base_image;
            console.log($scope.c_name);
        }, function (response) {
            // failed
            console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    $scope.GetData();
```

**Full response from  console.log(data);**

> you have received the data

```
{data: Array(1), status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}
config
:
{method: "POST", transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), url: "http://www.site.co.uk/one/two/getdata", date: {…}, …}
data
:
Array(1)
0
:
c_name
:
"ben"
d_text
:
[]
max_slots
:
2
resolution
:
(2) [1920, 1080]
slots
:
[{…}]
__v
:
0
_id
:
"59c92d6f45b79c8c110ee6ab"
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
headers
:
ƒ (c)
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
__proto__
:
Object
```

**And a screen shot**

[image]

Comment: Here $scope.c_name = data.c_name; Shouldn't it be response.c_name??

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.GetData = function () {
    $http({
        url: "http://www.site.co.uk/one/two/getdata",
        method: "POST",
        date: {},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function (response) {
        // success
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log('you have received the data ');
        console.log(data);
        // $scope.base_image = response.base_image; $scope.c_name = response.c_name;
        $scope.c_name = data.c_name;
        $scope.max_slots = data.max_slots;
        $scope.slot_image = data.slots.base_image;
        console.log($scope.c_name);
    }, function (response) {
        // failed
        console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
        console.log(response);
    });
};

$scope.GetData();
```

Replacing response with data should fix the issue.

Comment: Hmm I am getting 'angular.js:11655 TypeError: Cannot set property 'c_name' of undefined'

Comment: Can you please share whats response you are getting when you do console.log(data);

Comment: I have edited my answer 'var data = JSON.parse(response);'. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks trying now, ill also add the response from from the log in my question

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Please share response that you are getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155316/discussion-between-tavish-aggarwal-and-beep).

Answer (score 0):

I understood as you have to print JSON data for that I'm posting this answer, if you not expect this answer please post your question more clearly.

```
   $scope.GetData = function () {
    $http({
        url: "http://www.site.co.uk/one/two/getdata",
        method: "POST",
        date: {},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(function (response) {
        // success
        console.log('you have received the data ');
        console.log(response); // if the response data is in json
        console.log(angular.toJson(response)); // if the response data is in json
        // $scope.base_image = response.base_image; $scope.c_name = response.c_name;
        $scope.c_name = response.c_name;
        $scope.max_slots = response.max_slots;
        $scope.slot_image = response.slots.base_image;
        console.log($scope.c_name);

    }, function (response) {
        // failed
        console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
        console.log(response);
    });
};

$scope.GetData();
```